# How can assign only the three largest integers from a for loop in C into three separate variables?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that takes two user inputs (x and y), checks all numbers in the interval for all prime numbers, and then prints only the three largest prime numbers if available. So far, my code checks all the prime numbers in an interval starting from the largest to the smallest.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void inputXY(int *x, int *y) {
    printf("Enter value of x: ");
    scanf("%d", x);
    printf("Enter value of y: ");
    scanf("%d", y);
}

void swap(int*x, int*y){
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}

int primechecker(int divisor,int dividend){ 
    if(dividend==divisor) return 1; 
    else if(dividend%divisor==0) return 0;
    else primeChecker(divisor+1,dividend);
    }

void largestonly(int*counter, int*largest1, int*largest2, int*largest3){
    int temp;
    temp=*counter;
    if (temp>*largest1&&*largest2) ///incomplete attempt
}

void printlargest(int *x, int *y, int*largest1, int*largest2, int*largest3){ ///I do not know if this would work, since I have not equated largest1, largest2, and largest3 to zeroes. My idea here is that, if any specific variables are empty, different specific lines  should be printed.
    if (*largest1==0&&(*largest2&&*largest3!=0)) {
        printf("There are two prime numbers: ");
        printf("%d, %d", *largest2, *largest3);
    }
    else if (*largest1&&*largest2==0&&*largest3!=0){
        printf("There is only one prime number: ");
        printf("%d", *largest3);
    }
    else if (*largest1&&*largest2&&largest3!=0){
        printf("The three largest prime numbers between %d and %d are: ", *x, *y);
        printf("%d, %d, %d", *largest1, *largest2, *largest3);
    }
    else if (*largest1&&*largest2&&largest3==0){
        printf("No prime numbers found!");
    } 

}
int main(){
    int x,y,largest1, largest2, largest3, counter, divisor, dividend, i;
    divisor=2;
    dividend=counter;
    inputXY(&x, &y);
    if ((x&&y==0),(x&&y==1)) printf("Invalid range!\n");
    if (x>y) swap(&x, &y);
    for (i=0; i<=3; i++){
        for(counter=y;counter>=x;counter--) {
            if (primechecker(divisor,counter)==1) largestonly(&counter, &largest1, &largest2, &largest3);
        }
    }
    printlargest(&x, &y, &largest1, &largest2, &largest3);
    return 0;
}
```

I have yet to successfully write a working function that can sort all the integers produced by the for loop in `main()`. It is the `largestonly()` function as seen above. In relation to that, my `printlargest()` function undoubtedly does not work. My idea in here is that if `largest1` does not contain any value (or is equal to `0` or some other more appropriate value that I could not think of), the function will only print the two largest prime numbers found. Relatively, if both `largest1` and `largest2` are empty, only the largest prime number will be printed. If all variables are empty, it should print `"No prime numbers found!"`. I am very lost with what to do with my code at the moment so any type of help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you sorting?  You are searching through the values in descending order, and they should never get out of order. It would be cleaner if you used a data structure other than 3 integers named `largest?` (even a simple array will work), but even if you use 3 separate variables there's no reason for them to ever be unsorted.

Comment: I guess I used the wrong term. What I really want is to assign the three largest values into largest1, largest2, and largest3. I am also not allowed to use arrays yet. This is a homework I have in school.

Comment: There is no need to sort.  It is enough to split the array in 3 parts and recursively apply the `max3` function on each part.  At the end of each recursive call you will have 3 arrays of length 3 each (supposing the `max3` returns an array of 3 elements), so 9 elements in total, and take the 3 largest elements (by comparing, not by sorting) of those 9.   There is some work to do however, it is not so direct.

Comment: Hi alinsoar. Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I am not yet allowed to use arrays in this particular code.

Comment: `primechecker` !- `primeChecker`.

Comment: function and variable name choices are not helping to make your intentions clear.  I suggest adding a brief comment block just above each function with a short description of what it is supposed to do.   This simple exercise might even shed some light on how you can better code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to do here.

First, pay attention to the line 21, you call a `primeChecker()` function that doesn't exist. It will raise an error when compiling.

Second, you don't have to "sort" anything. You only have to store the prime numbers into the variables as they arrive. I noticed you consider `largest3` to be the first one that has to be filled (at least it is what can be understood from `printlargest()`), this gives us the following:

```c
void largestonly(int counter, int* largest1, int* largest2, int* largest3){
    if(*largest3 == 0) 
        *largest3 = counter;
    else if(*largest2 == 0)
        *largest2 = counter;
    else if(*largest1 == 0)
        *largest1 = counter;
}
```

Additionally, there is no need to pass the address of counter in the first place, as you won't need to modify it.

Lastly, in the `main()` function, you don't need a double loop. Think of it this way. If you were to do the exercise mentally, you'd go down the numbers, check if they were primes, and write them down if they satisfy the conditions: being primes and being the first, second or third. You wouldn't need to do it 3 times. Hence:

```c
int main(){
    int x,y;
    inputXY(&x, &y);
    int largest1 = 0;
    int largest2 = 0;
    int largest3 = 0;
    int divisor = 2;
    if ((x&&y==0),(x&&y==1)) printf("Invalid range!\n");
    if (x>y) swap(&x, &y);
    for(int counter=y;counter>=x;counter--) {
        if (primechecker(divisor,counter)==1) 
            largestonly(counter, &largest1, &largest2, &largest3);
    }
    printlargest(&x, &y, &largest1, &largest2, &largest3);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, the way you declared your variables without initializing them can sometimes be dangerous. In this case, as `largest1`, `largest2` and `largest3` weren't set to 0, you'd have had no chance to trigger any of the `printlargest()` cases. It may be because you were stuck on a part of your program you thought would also handle that but I still want to point it out, just in case.

EDIT: you could also add a condition in the `for` loop such that if `largest1` is not equal to 0, it exits the loop. It would prevent the program to loop through (potentially) big amount of numbers when you already have everything you need. It would look like this (with the existing `for` loop, for context):

```c
for(int counter=y;counter>=x;counter--) {
    if (primechecker(divisor,counter)==1) 
        largestonly(counter, &largest1, &largest2, &largest3);
    if(largest1 != 0)
        break;
}
```

Hope this clears out the issues you had, feel free to ask anything if necessary, or to point out things I'd have misunderstood in your question.

Here's the full code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void inputXY(int *x, int *y) {
    printf("Enter value of x: ");
    scanf("%d", x);
    printf("Enter value of y: ");
    scanf("%d", y);
}

void swap(int*x, int*y){
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}

int primechecker(int divisor,int dividend){ 
    if(dividend==divisor) return 1; 
    else if(dividend%divisor==0) return 0;
    else primechecker(divisor+1,dividend);
    }

void largestonly(int counter, int* largest1, int* largest2, int* largest3){
    if(*largest3 == 0) 
        *largest3 = counter;
    else if(*largest2 == 0)
        *largest2 = counter;
    else if(*largest1 == 0)
        *largest1 = counter;
}

void printlargest(int *x, int *y, int*largest1, int*largest2, int*largest3){ ///I do not know if this would work, since I have not equated largest1, largest2, and largest3 to zeroes. My idea here is that, if any specific variables are empty, different specific lines  should be printed.
    if (*largest1==0&&(*largest2&&*largest3!=0)) {
        printf("There are two prime numbers: ");
        printf("%d, %d", *largest2, *largest3);
    }
    else if (*largest1&&*largest2==0&&*largest3!=0){
        printf("There is only one prime number: ");
        printf("%d", *largest3);
    }
    else if (*largest1&&*largest2&&largest3!=0){
        printf("The three largest prime numbers between %d and %d are: ", *x, *y);
        printf("%d, %d, %d", *largest1, *largest2, *largest3);
    }
    else if (*largest1&&*largest2&&largest3==0){
        printf("No prime numbers found!");
    } 

}
int main(){
    int x,y;
    inputXY(&x, &y);
    int largest1 = 0;
    int largest2 = 0;
    int largest3 = 0;
    int divisor = 2;
    if ((x&&y==0),(x&&y==1)) printf("Invalid range!\n");
    if (x>y) swap(&x, &y);
    for(int counter=y;counter>=x;counter--) {
        if (primechecker(divisor,counter)==1) 
            largestonly(counter, &largest1, &largest2, &largest3);
    }
    printlargest(&x, &y, &largest1, &largest2, &largest3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much! I didn't know the typographical error in my call function for primechecker, thank you for pointing that out. I would just like to say that your answer was really easy to understand for a beginner like me. I will try this and check back here for any additional inputs. Thank you!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much! I have marked this answer as accepted.

Comment: I found this addition
`if(largest1 != 0) break;`
to be extra helpful.

Comment: Glad I was able to provide help!

Comment: Hi! For some reason I keep getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` every time I enter 1 as both x and y inputs. And when I enter 0 on both, the program just terminates without printing anything. Is there anything wrong with the line `if ((x&&y==0),(x&&y==1),(x&&y<0)) printf("Invalid range!\n");` in `main()`?

Comment: I must admit that I have no idea regarding this, as it is not behaving the same way when inputting 0. It may be interesting to open a new question?

Answer (score 2):

First, define how you would check for a prime number:

```c
bool is_prime(int num)
{
    if (num < 2)
        return false;
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / i; ++i)
        if (num % i == 0)
        return false;
    
    return true;
}
```

Then, define a function that returns the 3 largest prime numbers in a given interval:

```c
void get_max_3_in_range(int lo, int hi, int *max1, int *max2, int *max3)
{
    *max1 = 0; // smallest
    *max2 = 0;
    *max3 = 0; // largest
    
    int round = 0;
    
    for (int i = lo; i <= hi; ++i) {
        if (is_prime(i)) {
            if (round % 3 == 0) *max1 = i;
            if (round % 3 == 1) *max2 = i;
            if (round % 3 == 2) *max3 = i;
            ++round;
        }
    }
    
    if (*max1 > *max2) swap_int(max1, max2);
    if (*max2 > *max3) swap_int(max2, max3);
}
```

Here is your `swap()`:

```c
void swap_int(int *v1, int *v2)
{
    int tmp = *v1;
    *v1 = *v2;
    *v2 = tmp;
}
```

Driver program:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int x, y;
    inputXY(&x, &y);
    
    int max1, max2, max3;
    get_max_3_in_range(x, y, &max1, &max2, &max3);
    
    printf("x = %d\ty = %d\n", x, y);
    printf("max1 = %d\tmax2 = %d\tmax3 = %d\n", max1, max2, max3);
}
```

Output:

```txt
Enter value of x: 0
Enter value of y: 100
x = 0   y = 100
max1 = 83   max2 = 89   max3 = 97
```

You can choose what to output in case one or more of the maximums is/are zero. Here, I chose to print them all.

---

**Side note:** Your `inputXY()` is very error-prone. Because if the user enters a string, your code will break. `scanf()` returns a value that you must check.

Following is a better version:

```c
void inputXY(int *x, int *y)
{
    for(;;) {
        printf("Enter value of x: ");
        if (scanf("%d", x) != 1)
            flush_stdin();
        else
            break;
    }
    
    flush_stdin();
    
    for(;;) {
        printf("Enter value of y: ");
        if (scanf("%d", y) != 1)
            flush_stdin();
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

And `flush_stdin()` (*Never* do `fflush(stdin)`!!) will clear what remained in the buffer, in case the user didn't enter (just) a number:

```c
void flush_stdin(void)
{
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
}
```

Comment: Thank so much for the help! I will be applying this to my code and check back for any additional inputs.

Comment: Hi! I eventually marked the answer below as accepted as his answer already matched the existing functions in my code. I do sincerely appreciate the help though. Thank you!